# Selecting a specific row from a table

Tags: sql, mysql

How can I select a particular row from a table?

I want to do achieve something like the following:

```
select * from 
    (select * from tablename1 where type=1 order by id desc) 
where rownum = 5

select * from 
    (select * from tablename1 where type=1 order by id desc) 
where rownum = $variable
```

Comment: From what database?  Different vendors handle this differently.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `LIMIT` keyword:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE (stuff...) LIMIT $rownum,1;
```

If you pass 2 numbers to `LIMIT`, it treats the first as an offset and the second as a number of results to return (whereas if you pass only 1 number, it just treats it as a number of results). Thus asking for `LIMIT $rownum,1` you'll get back only one row, which is the one at position $rownum (keep in mind that rows are indexed starting from 0).

Comment: This is a MySQL keyword. What the OP posted above is PL/SQL syntax. SQL Server uses `row_number() over (order by col)`. And now you know.

Comment: Actually, what the OP posted was valid mysql syntax as well (at least, not counting the row number bit which is what they were asking about in the first place). Not to mention their comment stating they're using mysql.

Comment: @Dav: `rownum` is not a function in MySQL, and the OP posted that comment *after* mine. And I am not a time traveler. Yet. You get +1 for the now correct answer :)

Comment: @Eric yes, but they were looking for something *like* what they posted - if they were looking for what the posted, why would they be asking here? :) Anywho, no worries.

Comment: @ dav,eric @brian i have posted one more questions on SQL plz help me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805169/random-row-from-mssql-db-using-dlinq